# Content-type Error while passing and reading XML String Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I have an xml

```
<?xml version = .......
<A>1</A>
<B>2</>
</>
```

I am trying to convert this into a String and send this as payload to another application through Kafka

//Producer App

```
@EnableBinding(Source.class)

public class Producer {


      @InboundChannelAdapter(value = Source.OUTPUT, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "7000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
        public Message produceMessages() {

           //Converting xml to String here
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filename)));
            String line;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while((line=br.readLine())!= null){
                sb.append(line.trim());

            string1 = sb.toString();

            Message<string> msg1 = MessageBuilder.withPayload(string1).build();

}
```

App.yml

```
spring:
  application:
     name: some-app
  cloud:
    stream:
      defaultBinder: kafka
      bindings:
        output:
          destination: someTopic
```

//Consumer

```
@EnableBinding(Interface1.class)
public class ConsumerApp {

    @StreamListener(Interface1.RECEIVE_FROM_SOURCE)
    public void handleMessage(Message message){

        String receivedPayload = message.getPayload().toString();
        logger.info(received payload >>> " +receivedPayload);

        someObject.someMethod(receivedPayload); ///this needs to have just xml string as parameter and throws error

    }
}
```

When I do this..

I get

```
received payload >>> "{"payload":"<?xmlns....<A>1</A><B>2</B>"}
```

And it errors out

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

How can I just get the value of the payload which is just a String ? Thank you.

Comment: Looks like that problem is in your code - clearly the payload **is** a `String`. It looks like someplace you are trying to cast a string to an `Object[]`. Show the full stack trace.

Comment: Try to add this also: `output.content-type: text/plain`. By default SCSt uses `application/json` and it doesn't sound like you want to deal with JSON conversion in between.